# MySQL count multiple foreign keys

Tags: mysql, count, foreign-keys

So I have a query where I select from the 'sites' table, and count the number of 'pages' using a foreign key

```
SELECT s_id, s_name, s_main_url, COUNT(p_id) AS numpages
FROM sites
INNER JOIN pages ON sites.s_id = pages.site_id
GROUP BY pages.site_id
ORDER BY s_id ASC
```

I want to add another foreign key to count, possibly more than one, so I tried the below

```
SELECT s_id, s_name, s_main_url, COUNT(p_id) AS numpages, COUNT(l_id) AS numlinks
FROM sites
INNER JOIN pages ON sites.s_id = pages.site_id
INNER JOIN links ON sites.s_id = links.site_id
GROUP BY pages.site_id, links.site_id
ORDER BY s_id ASC
```

The count for both numpages and numlinks are the same, and they seem to have multiplied all the tables results and is giving me some huge number that is incorrect

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider using sub-selects instead of JOIN and GROUP BY.

```
SELECT s_id, s_name, s_main_url, numpages, numlinks
FROM sites, 
(SELECT COUNT(p_id) as numpages FROM pages WHERE pages.site_id = sites.s_id) as cnt_pages,
(SELECT COUNT(l_id) as numlink FROM links WHERE links.site_id = sites.s_id) as cnt_links
ORDER BY s_id ASC
```

Comment: Thx for the reply :) Isnt this going to be less efficient on larger tables though?

Comment: No, internally the JOIN version and the sub-query version work exactly the same. You can rewrite the first query to sub-query version and  compare them with EXPLAIN command. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html

Comment: Hi, I just came across this as I have the same problem. However, I can't get this answer to work for me. It keeps saying "Unknown column 'sites.s_id' in 'where clause'". Is there anything special I have to do to be able to reference the tables in the outer query from the subquery?

Comment: Not sure if you ever solved this, but I did it by making the subquery like this - (SELECT count(*) FROM links WHERE links.site_id = sites.s_id) AS numlinks

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error: "Unknown column" of the table of outer query inside the inner query and solved in different way:

```
SELECT s_id, s_name, s_main_url, numpages, numlinks,
(SELECT COUNT(p_id) FROM pages WHERE pages.site_id = sites.s_id) as cnt_pages,
(SELECT COUNT(l_id) FROM links WHERE links.site_id = sites.s_id) as cnt_links
FROM sites, 
ORDER BY s_id ASC
```

It may be somehow slow, but works.